Overlay appears in fullscreen mode in Safari when video is paused
When a video in Safari is played in fullscreen mode and the user pauses it, an overlay (such as a play button or other controls) appears. This affects the user experience, as we want to avoid showing the overlay during fullscreen viewing after the video is paused.
Expected Behavior:
The overlay should not appear after the video is paused in fullscreen mode.
Steps to Reproduce:
Open a webpage https://slides-dev.pitchavatar.com/rtxuf in Safari.
Start playing the video.
Enter fullscreen mode.
Pause the video.
The overlay appears after the video is paused.
Screenshot:
enter image description here
We attempted to hide the overlay using the following JavaScript code:
const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
const overlayElement = document.querySelector('.overlay');

videoElement.addEventListener('pause', () => {
  if (document.fullscreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
    overlayElement.style.display = 'none'; // Hide overlay in fullscreen mode
  }
});

videoElement.addEventListener('play', () => {
  overlayElement.style.display = 'none'; // Hide overlay during playback
});

document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', () => {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
    overlayElement.style.display = 'block'; // Show overlay after exiting fullscreen mode
  }
});

And trying this methods Cannot disable/override context menu Safari fullscreen mode
